# Typescript: expand generic array type into a generic union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So what I want to achieve is following: I have type `P` which represents array of keys from an object `T`, so `P extends Array<keyof T>`. And I want to pass the `P` to `Omit<T, P>` to exclude given keys from that objects.

In TS code it looks like this

```js
export function excludeProps<T extends Record<string, any>, P extends Array<keyof T>>(
  object: T,
  ...propsToExclude: P
): Omit<T, P> {
  const filteredEntries = Object.entries(object).filter(([key]) => !propsToExclude.includes(key));
  return Object.fromEntries(filteredEntries);
}
```

This of course doesn't work because Omit expects a single key or union of keys, not an array. Is there a way to transform `P` so that it can be passed in? Or is there a better way to type this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite simple: turn the elements of the array into a union type by indexing with `[number]`.

```
export function excludeProps<
  T extends Record<string, any>, 
  P extends Array<keyof T>
>(
  object: T,
  ...propsToExclude: P
): Omit<T, P[number]> {
  const filteredEntries = Object.entries(object).filter(([key]) => !propsToExclude.includes(key));
  return Object.fromEntries(filteredEntries) as Omit<T, P[number]>
}
```

Also, you are gonna need a type assertion for the return type.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEV1GgGyQBNgAFKCMAZwB4AVPEGYFY6uAJWDWmNuowomFAHMANHACGKAJ4A+SWSYs2HAIJQoU2bQDWwWRARx68+QAoAUHDgQARgCseMAFynxNuADpfYSjT0EACiIIQkwO5kVgCU7gDyALaYMAxKANooSIn2wFAAuvJwAN5evCiCiJgELFDAxMEoQpjAHAC8cPFOLt6sza0WDs4YMd4I1bUWFukGsvkxcG1FAIT+VNRBoeGk3iLbA7MxMQDcXnUwSFC4XcMwY5SJjf3UFuM1efVPwq0LUhydyVS9AyWRyeUKVgAvlYYfgiKQKOsLMVpO4AERoyT2dGYuBoHGQyRoqRomJAA)

Comment: Nice, thanks for the quick answer! Can you please tell me more about that `[number]` syntax? Link to docs is just as good.

Comment: I don't think there is documentation specific for this. But you can see it that way: Types can always be indexed with `[]`. So an a type `Obj` with property `foo` can be indexed with `Obj["foo"]` to get the type of `foo`. Arrays have an index signature of type number. That's why indexing an array like `Arr[number]` will give you the type behind the index signature.